# Одинаковые действия контроллов, datasource которых ссылается на один bindingsource

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть несколько `Combobox` и `ListBox` элементов на форме. Их свойства `DataSource` ссылаются на общий `bindingsource`, который в свою очередь ссылается на коллекцию некоторых объектов.
Но происходит такая вещь: при выборе из списка `Combobox`'a выделяется соответствующий элемент в `ListBox` (а на Select стоит обработчик событий, так что это приводит к тем действиям, к которым он не должен приводить).
Я знаю, что привязка данных привязывает данные, но связывает ли оно ещё и действия?

Comment: Не поняла, один и тот же набор данных для обоих элементов?

Comment: @EllaSvetlaya Да. Есть класс "Человек", у которого есть свойство "Ранг" (Можно выбрать из перечисления). Есть форма с 2мя вкладками, на одной из которых добавление нового объекта "Человек", с установкой значения свойства "Ранг", и другая - выборка данных. Для выборки данных о нескольких людях логично, что можно выбрать несколько значений, в то время как на вкладки создания человека - только одно. Там и проявляется этот дефект.

Comment: Я бы их все-таки разделила...

Comment: Ранги добавляются пользователем динамически, так что никак.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А что если сделать 2 разных DataBindings (для Combobox и ListBox соответственно), а уже им в DataSource навесить одну коллекцию? Что значит "добавляются динамически" и почему такой вариант "никак"? DataBindings ведь на одну коллекцию будут ссылаться.

Comment: 2 разных - та же проблема. Добавляются динамически - пользователь во время выполнения заполняет поля и формирует коллекцию Рангов.

Comment: Попробовал на пустом проекте - сработало. Видимо косяки в настоящем проекте связано с другим.